# Custom tab size based on file extension

Tags: atom-editor

To get along better with my coworkers, I have atom configured with 2-space tabs, but in some files, I prefer 4. I'm trying to figure another file type, in this case, my Foo.pro files that are created with Qt Creator.

I've tried a few dozen things, and nothing seems to work. I'm editing my `~/.atom/config.cson` and then restarting atom, and there's no change.

Here's my latest attempt:

```coffee
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.pro": [
        "pro"
      ]
    disabledPackages: [
      "autocomplete-plus"
      "markdown-preview"
      "markdown-preview-plus"
      "spell-check"
    ]
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
    themes: [
      "atom-light-ui"
      "one-light-syntax"
    ]
  editor: {}
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "283f523f-3348-4956-97f6-a73675e6e9c6"
  "tree-view":
    hideVcsIgnoredFiles: true
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
".basic.html.text":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
".html.source":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
".source.pro":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
".shell.source":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
".shtml.source":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
```

I'm fairly sure some of these others aren't working, either. Within Atom, if I open my .pro file and do Alt-Cmnd-P, it says the file type is `text.plain.null-grammar`. And tab width is still 2 characters. So clearly I'm doing something wrong.

You'll notice I'm attempting to define a custom file type (way at the top) and then define the tab length (near the bottom).

Comment: What's `Alt-Cmnd-P`? `editor:log-cursor-scope`?

Comment: Do you have a grammar installed for `source.pro`?

Comment: @wjandrea On mac, that tells you what language it thinks your file is. And no, I don't have a particular grammar. Although there's a language-qtpro package. I'll try installing that and see what happens.

Comment: @wjandrea Installing that language package seems to have improved behavior. It didn't even occur to me I should go look. Now I'll have to be aware of that. Alt-cmnd-p now reports `source.pro` and `keyword.operator.qtpro`. I'm not sure what that second one is, but things are working the way I want.

Comment: I think you're seeing `keyword.operator.qtpro` because Alt-Cmd-P runs `editor:log-cursor-scope`, and your cursor is in the middle of a language operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to install a grammar for .pro files, for example [`language-qtpro`](https://atom.io/packages/language-qtpro), otherwise the `source.pro` scope won't be active.

(I believe this works because of [the `fileTypes` field](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/#language-recognition) of a grammar package, which activates [the `scopeName` field](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/#basic-fields).)

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution. I didn't re-edit my config.cson, so I don't know if they're working together, or it magically worked for another reason. But I'm back to 4-space tabs where I want them.

Comment: @Joseph That'd be the config :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that Atom reverses the scopes for the language in `config.cson`, so rather than using `.source.pro` it should be `.pro.source` (as with the others in your example). At least that's what it does, when you set up indentation in the package settings for a language.

Since you mentioned that you want to get along better with colleagues: Have you looked into using the editor-agnostic [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) standard to share indentation settings with them? Whenever your project contains an `.editorconfig` file, that will override your personal preferences that you would use when no such file exists. EditorConfig is supported by *many* editors, directly or through plugins.

Comment: Weird, one of the top-level scopes in my config is `".source.yaml"`, and it's working fine

Comment: I thought this was correct, but actually, after running a quick test, both work: `.<language>.source` and `.source.<language>`, at least for Python. I think the actual problem is that OP doesn't have a grammar installed for `source.pro`, although I'm shaky on the details.